# Linq to XML parsing

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml as shown below.

I need to write a method that takes a string input (“IsAuthorFilterNeeded” or “IsTitleFilterNeeded”) and returns the book code values under that node.

Suppose if parameter is “IsAuthorFilterNeeded” it should return 5,6,7,8

I tried to write a Linq2XML query to retrieve this, but I am not happy with the code as it is not readable and has many hardcoded strings.Here is my linq2xml query.

```
public IList<string> GetBookCodes(string filterOption)
{
    IList<string> requiredValues = null;

    foreach (var node in _xml.Descendants("BookOptions"))
    {
        if (node.Parent.Attribute("Name").Value == "ScienceBooks")
        {
            var requiredNode = node.Elements("Property").Attributes("Value").First(x => x.Parent.FirstAttribute.Value == filterOption);
            requiredValues = requiredNode.Parent.Descendants("BookCode").Attributes("Value").ToArray().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

            break;
        }
    }
    return requiredValues;
}
```

Is there any other way to achieve this result with simpler code .

```
<LibraryRack Id="3" Name="ScienceBooks">
      <Books>
        <Book Id ="1" Name="Book1"></Book>
        <Book Id ="2" Name="Book2"></Book >
        <Book Id ="3" Name="Book3"></Book>
      </Books>
      <BookOptions>
        <Property Name="IsAuthorFilterNeeded" Value ="1">
          <BookCode Value="5" />
          <BookCode Value="6" />
          <BookCode Value="7" />
          <BookCode Value="8" />
        </Property>
        <Property Name="IsTitleFilterNeeded" Value ="0">
          <BookCode Value="2"/>
          <BookCode Value="3"/>
          <BookCode Value="4"/>
          <BookCode Value="7"/>
          <BookCode Value="129"/>
        </Property>
       </BookOptions> 

    </LibraryRack>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think fluent api looks more readable here

```
var propertyFilter = "IsAuthorFilterNeeded";
var query = xdoc.Descendants("LibraryRack")
                .Where(lr => (string)lr.Attribute("Name") == "ScienceBooks")
                .Descendants("Property")
                .Where(p => (string)p.Attribute("Name") == propertyFilter)
                .Descendants()
                .Select(bc => (int)bc.Attribute("Value"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This bit of LINQ should do the trick (once your XML is fixed):

```
public IList<string> GetBookCodes(string filterOption)
{
    return (from property in _xml.Descendants("Property")
            where (string)property.Attribute("Name") == filterOption
            from value in property.Descendants("BookCode").Attributes("Value")                
            select (string)value).ToList();
}
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to put the `where` clause *before* the second `from` clause.

Comment: Where in your code have you mentioned you need to look for "ScienceBooks" node ?

Answer (score 1):

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("somedata.xml",FileMode.Open))
{
  var result = XDocument.Load(fs).Descendants("BookOptions").
                                  Descendants("Property").
                                  Where(c => { return c.Attribute("Name").Value.Trim() == "IsAuthorFilterNeeded"; }).
                                  Descendants().Select(xe => xe.Attribute("Value"));

  result.ToList().ForEach((val) => Console.WriteLine(val));
}
```